# Adding header to output csv from fast-csv package

Tags: javascript, node.js, csv, fast-csv

I am generating a CSV file from an SQL Query using the [fast-csv](https://www.npmjs.com/package/fast-csv) node package. Here is the relevant bit of code.

```
const dataStream = client.query(copyTo(q));
const writeStream =   fs.createWriteStream('output.csv');
dataStream.pipe(writeStream);
dataStream.on('end', async function () {
    console.log("Closing client");
    await client.end();
});
```

This above code is generating the CSV file just fine, but I am not get the header row added to the output csv.

Question: how do I add a header line to the csv output file?

Comment: will this link help - https://github.com/C2FO/fast-csv/blob/HEAD/docs/formatting.md#examples-headers ?

Comment: umm, that link is broken

Answer (score 0):

add the headers like this

const csv = require('fast-csv')

const ws = fs.createWriteStream(`${plant_id}.csv`);
csv.write([
dataRecived,
],
{headers: ['header 1', 'header 2', 'header 3', 'header 4']}
).pipe(ws);